# Where to store big sqlite file outside repository in python pytest testing

Tags: python, sqlite, testing, pytest, storage

I have a repository with automation tests, and I'm using there db.sqlite which is currently in my repository tree like data/db.sqlite. But it is not pushed to repository (gitignored).

However I need this file also in CI process since I'm getting data from there and I wonder what is the best way to use it locally and in CI, with the easiest way managing that.

This db.sqlite weigh over 200mb.

One thing I could do is to keep it in repository, but I don't think it's smart -> Because it would grow the repository weigh also then docker tests image etc. And in future there might be another db's like that and I would need to store them all.

What is the best way to manage files like those?

The only thing I thought of is to add this to repo, but this seems wrong. There must be better way to do this.

Comment: Do you REALLY need a DB that big for your tests?

Comment: @buran Not always -> usually I could use something smaller like 50mb, but there are cases that I would need all of it unfortunately.

Comment: create a separate repo and host it there?

Comment: not sure what advantage it gives me @TeejayBruno -> I would have lighter main repository, but still I would need to manage with ansible or smth to download another repository, and put it in some place on runner (?) and connect it to my tests, or you are thinking on something else?

Comment: you'd have the option to download the test db as part of your test run and clean it up after the fact.

Comment: Generally I'm only getting data from DB and i'm not saving anything there so there is nothing to clean up, my app is used with different clients and db is client specific, so in future i'd like to have tests for other clients too and i would give just different database and I should have 90% work done when I will just switch sqlite. Once in a while I want also to download new prod-like db and use it in my tests.